# Python web crawling: different query strings in URL lead to same page

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, query-string, urllib

When validating URLs to be added to the queue, one of the problems I can't seem to overcome is parsing query strings. Two different URLs with different query strings (actual paths and query strings):

A: https://foo.com/page.php?pid=1656&action=follow&dcb60b7d1c313991fcc024e36bf63bc6=1

B: https://foo.com/page.php?pid=1656&action=follow&5c047b4476d6db958223b009e8aa8b24=1

Both of these URLs are the same page, yet because their URLs are different due to that last query string parameter, my code interprets them to be unique. All of the query string parameter before that are necessary for me to reach the page, but the final one is not. The end result is a horribly inefficient script, acquiring and crawling perhaps hundreds of different URLs all of which lead to the same location. What I need is an effective way to recognize and eliminate that long-winded query string parameter and keep the others. Urllib.parse doesn't really have any obvious solutions, I can easily parse that query string using that library but there's no good way to validate the query strings for necessity.

Comment: Why not just check the query string length and remove query string parameters that are too long from determining wether or not a query is unique?

Comment: @MohammadAli thank you for the response, I think I will experiment with that. I will have to see how long the long character parameters can be, because if they are too short I might end up chopping off useful parameters. Time will tell. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, the only other way I see what you want being done is to download a copy of the webpage and store the page or a hash of it in a database which will let you see if any new URLs you are scraping return the same content as another URL when you compare the hashes